# Screen flickering on Inspiron 16 Plus 7610 after installing 20.04 LTS and deepin 20.2.3

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, video, deepin

After sometime flickering it prints the message:

```
CPU pipe B FIFO underun
```

I've tried to disable C-states as suggested in [[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588457/drmintel-cpu-fifo-underrun-irq-handler-i915-error-cpu-pipe-a-fifo-underru) but it has not worked.

I've tried to disable the safe boot, but it has not worked as well.

This is the version of Inspiron 16 Plus 7610 with:

- i7-11800H
- GeForce RTX 3060 6GB

Windows 10 that comes with it seems to be working fine so far but I cannot get it working with Ubuntu.

I've tried to install deepin 20.2.3 as well but I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it you need to add a param to the kernel initialization, you can do that by pressing E at the grub screen or following these steps:

1. sudo (editor command) /etc/default/grub
2. Comment out this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

3. Add this line instead:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
```

4. Save and close your editor
5. sudo update-grub
6. reboot

It seems that starting with either kernel 5.2.0 or 5.3.0 they decided to enable PSR (Panel Self Refresh) by default.
Depending on the hardware, this periodic panel refreshing may cause the screen flickering.

I found the answer at:

- https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/XPS-13-7390-Ubuntu-Screen-flickering/td-p/7430121/page/3
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339302
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361640/screen-flickering-on-inspiron-16-plus-7610-after-installing-20-04-lts/1364348#1364348